# How to calculate the sum of this Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you calculate

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty {{2i \choose i}\over 4^i\cdot (2i+1)}$$

Wolfram gives ${\pi \over 2}$, but I have no idea how it got this.

Comment: Consider $\sum_{i=0}^\infty {{2i \choose i}x^i\over (2i+1)}$ and replace $x$ by $1/4$. This looks to be a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}\binom{2i}{i} &= \frac{2^i(2i - 1)(2i-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1}{i!}\\
& = \frac{(-1)^i 4^i(1/2 - i)(3/2 - i)\cdots (-3/2)(-1/2)}{i!}\\
& = (-1)^i4^i\binom{-1/2}{i}
\end{align}

and use the monotone convergence theorem to write

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2i}{i}}{4^i(2i+1)} &=\sum_{i = 0}^\infty 4^{-i}\binom{2i}{i}\int_0^1 x^{2i}\, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \sum_{i = 0}^\infty 4^{-i}\binom{2i}{i}x^{2i}\, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{i}(-x^2)^i dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}\, dx\\
&= \arcsin(1) - \arcsin(0)\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: much better imo (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$\frac{\arcsin 2x}{2x}= \sum_{i=0}^\infty {{2i \choose i}x^{2i}\over (2i+1)}$$